# Can we create module from shared object ie '*.so' files by renaming it to '$modulename-$version.tm'?

Tags: tcl

Want to create module from shared object file `x.so` to avoid `load` command. Shared object C source code `x.c` defines package `p` with version `1` in it.

I renamed `x.so` to `p-1.tm` and added its path in `::tcl::tm::path` and 
used `package require p 1`

Its showing error that it cannot read command. It is because the main file is `x.so` instead of `x.tcl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modules are *always* `source`d. Making them include a loadable library as well requires some trickery. Here's one way. Make a Tcl script like this:

```
apply {{scriptname realname} {
    set script [open $scriptname]
    chan configure $script -eofchar \x1a
    chan read $script
    chan configure $script -translation binary
    chan seek $script 1 current; # Reset EOF state and skip past the EOF character
    set f [file tempfile filename $realname.so]
    chan copy $script $f
    chan close $f
    chan close $script
    tailcall load $filename $realname; # Used to find the _Init function
}} [info script] YourRealLibraryName
```

Concatenate it with an ASCII EOF char (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>) and then concatenate your real shared library on the end after that, saving it all as the module file. When the script is sourced, it will copy the library off the end of itself into a temporary file and load it from that.

---

This depends on the fact that `source` always configures the channel it uses to read the script to use the EOF character to act as an end-of-file marker, even on systems that wouldn't normally use it. You can then read past that and extract any payload data you want from there on. Concatenating a loadable library on the end is trivial, but it needs to be extracted elsewhere to actually be fed into `load`. Internally, *all* loading of dynamic libraries in Tcl goes through `load`; it's the only command that knows how to do it. We're just preparing the way for it (and real files are required by default since we're delegating the actual loading to the operating system library calls that do the job; `file tempfile` is perfect for this job!). Finally, we wrap everything in an `apply` and `tailcall load` at the end so that we clean away all the filename manipulation machinery is cleaned away neatly.

More sophisticated approaches using virtual filesystems are possible, but take far more code to explain. They're still just doing this sort of thing, but with more trickery hidden out of sight.